# MySQL replication constantly checking tables

Tags: mysql, replication

I recently moved one of our slave databases to a new server, the database is purely used for offsite replication/backup and doesn't handle any of the live traffic.

Since moving, the new server seems to constantly want to run `CHECK TABLE` across the whole database. We've got a a few large tables, one being ~10GB, so it locks everything up for a few minutes while it's checking the table and in result queues up the queries.

I've looked at possible causes as to why it needs to check so often, but can't seem to find a reason.

I was wondering if anyone here has experienced this, or would know of a reason?

Comment: what mysql version was the old server running, and what is the new one running? Also, on a limb, have you verified the binary log doesn't contain the `CHECK TABLE` statements?

Comment: Are you seeing any messages in the error log file to the tune that the table is marked as crashed?

Comment: Please show your my.cnf

Comment: @DTest We're using MySQL Ver 14.14 Dist 5.1.61. I've checked the log and no mention of `CHECK TABLE`

Comment: @PythianMoore Nope, error log is clear.

Comment: Debian and Ubuntu automatically do a check tables on startup. How long has the server been running?  Check /etc/mysql/debian-start

Answer (score 2):

If your database tables are MyISAM, you might have given the server option [`myisam-recover`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_myisam-recover) in your my.cnf, which will turn on automatic MyISAM checking.

> If recovery is enabled, each time mysqld opens a MyISAM table, it checks whether the table is marked as crashed or was not closed properly.

Comment: We do have `myisam-recover = BACKUP`, but the config is the same as the previous server, of which this issue never occurred.

Comment: Regardless, I would comment that out to see if the issue goes away on your new server, just to verify.